# AutoMapper from a list to collection grouped by date

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a parent-child source which I wish to map using AutoMapper to a parent-date-child destination (eg. the destination groups the child data by date using a SortedSet collection.

The intention is that you can then use the SortedSet to obtain all the 'children' that are for that date.

I'm currently using a an [IValueResolver](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers) which loops through the Children of the source and individually maps and then adds them to the SortedSet. As can be seen from the code below, this needs to create a new item in the SortedSet collection if the date doesn't exist.

Is there a better way of configuring the mapping?

I'm aware that AutoMapper can map lists (rather than just individual list items), but because of the requirement to group the destination items by date, I'm not sure if there's a better solution to what I'm currently using.

### Source types

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Days = new SortedSet<DayViewModel>();
    }

    public SortedSet<DayViewModel> Days { get; set; }
}

public class ModelChild 
{
    public DateTime Started { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class ModelParent
{
    public string Name;
    public IList<ModelChild> Children = new List<ModelChild>();
}
```

### Destination types

```
public class ChildViewModel 
{
    public DateTime Started { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class DayViewModel
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public DayViewModel()
    {
        Children = new List<ChildViewModel>();
    }

    public IList<ChildViewModel> Children { get; set; }
}

public class DayComparer : IComparer<DayViewModel>
{
    public int Compare(DayViewModel x, DayViewModel y)
    {
        return x.Date.CompareTo(y.Date);
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Days = new SortedSet<DayViewModel>(new DayComparer());
    }

    public SortedSet<DayViewModel> Days { get; set; }
}
```

### IValueResolver

```
public class DaysResolver : IValueResolver
{
    public ResolutionResult Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
    {
        var person = (ModelParent)source.Context.SourceValue;
        var vm = (ViewModel)source.Context.DestinationValue;

        foreach (var modelChild in person.Children)
        {
            var file = Mapper.Map<ChildViewModel>(modelChild);
            var day = GetDay(vm, file.Started);
            day.Children.Add(file);
        }
        return source.Ignore();
    }

    private static DayViewModel GetDay(ViewModel model, DateTime key)
    {
        var dayViewModel = model.Days.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Date == key);

        if (dayViewModel == null)
        {
            dayViewModel = new DayViewModel
            {
                Date = key
            };

            model.Days.Add(dayViewModel);
        }
        return dayViewModel;
    }
}
```

### Mapping

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<ModelChild, ChildViewModel>();

    Mapper.CreateMap<ModelParent, ViewModel>()
        .ForMember(d => d.Days, x => x.ResolveUsing<DaysResolver>());

    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option I've come up with is to move the DayViewModel lookup/create logic into a ContructUsing method for a mapping between ModelChild and DayViewModel. eg.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ModelChild, DayViewModel>()
    .ConstructUsing(context =>
    {
        var key = ((ModelChild) context.SourceValue).Started;
        var daysCollection = (SortedSet<DayViewModel>) context.Parent.DestinationValue;

        var dayViewModel = daysCollection.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Date == key);

        if (dayViewModel == null)
        {
            dayViewModel = new DayViewModel
            {
                Date = key
            };

            daysCollection.Add(dayViewModel);
        }

        dayViewModel.Children.Add(Mapper.Map<ChildViewModel>(context.SourceValue));
        return dayViewModel;
    })
    .ForAllMembers(d => d.Ignore());
```

This still calls Map again explicitly, but I'm open to other suggestions

Comment: As an automapper noobie, it's good to know that `ConstructUsing()` brings great flexibility and allows solve this issue